# Print a variables value in a module

Tags: python

I have a lot of constant variables in my application.  In this application I import a module.  As part of testing I would like to call from a function in said imported module that prints out the variable's name and their values.

OK so this is not my code but this shows the concept of what I would like to do:

```
-main.py-
import mymodule
DEBUG = True
BATCH = False
ShowVars(['DEBUG','BATCH'])

-mymodule.py-
def ShowVars(varlist):
  for name in varlist:
    print('{} -> {}').format(name,eval(name))
```

I get at error at the eval(name) that 'DEBUG is not defined' of course but I am trying to get this concept working.

One way I found is to change main.py as:

```
-main.py-
import mymodule
DEBUG = True
BATCH = False
mymodule.DEBUG=DEBUG
mymodule.BATCH=BATCH
ShowVars(['DEBUG','BATCH'])
```

Then things work but I'm not sure I like it...  Any ideas or anecdotes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all that answered!  Your insight got me going down a long path.  I tried using all the techniques and found that the inspect module did what I needed.  But as I worked on implementing that into our real code I found that where I was in the frame stack was going to be important.  I was able to accomplish that with the inspect module by using multiple `.f_backs` but I ultimately went with sys._getframe() because you can give it a depth.  So my original mymodule.py was changed to:

```
-mymodule.py-
import sys
import traceback

def ShowVars(varlist):
  depth = len(traceback.extract_stack())-1
  f = sys._getframe(depth)
  for name in varlist:
    print('{} -> {}').format(name,f.f_locals.get(name,f.f_globals.get(name)))
```

Comment: Why do you use `traceback.extract_stack()` ? Aren't `sys._getframe(1)` or `inspect.currentframe().f_back` enough?

Comment: I use it to give me the depth of the stack.  In this example it works because I know the depth is 1 ( so sys._getframe(1) or inspect.currentframe().f_back) is enough.  But this in my real application I don't always know the depth of the call.

Comment: That's because x wasn't defined prior to your call to c().  I just added x=4 prior to the call to c() and I got x -> 4 back as expected.  What the depth gives you is how far from the root depth (0) you are so that you can do the call back to the root.

Comment: I was also able to do the depth=len(inspect.stack())-1 as well but I already had traceback and sys loaded and utilized.

Comment: Even though I defined `x = 4` as global variable, I expected I got `1` . Do you expect `print(x)` in function `a` to print `4` instead of `1`?   http://ideone.com/QVkVqC   I didn't mean you should use `inspect.stack` instead of `traceback.extract_stack`.

Comment: Yes a from the root stack.  My real method gives the ability to decide depth.  To get the x == 1 you expected then Depth needs to be 1.  Both inspect.stack and traceback.extract_stack give about the same data so I found either could be used.  I already had traceback module loaded (as well as sys) so I went with that.

Comment: BTW I certainly like the conversation.  This has been very interesting.  Although I feel I've spent a bit to much time on it.  It has given me a real understanding of the python stack.

Comment: If you want root stack, you don't need to look `f_locals`. `print('{} -> {}').format(name,f.f_globals.get(name))` or `print('{} -> {}').format(name,f.f_locals.get(name))` is enough (because at the root stack, `f_locals == f_globals`)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html):

```
import inspect

def ShowVars(varlist):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    g = frame.f_globals
    l = frame.f_locals
    for name in varlist:
        print('{} -> {}'.format(name, l.get(name, g.get(name))))
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE**

main.py:

```
import mymodule
DEBUG = True
BATCH = False
mymodule.ShowVars(DEBUG, BATCH)
```

mymodule.py:

```
import inspect

def ShowVars(*values):
    line = inspect.stack()[1][4][0]
    names = line.rsplit('(', 1)[-1].split(')', 1)[0] # Extract argument names.
    names = map(str.strip, names.split(','))
    for name, value in zip(names, values):
        print('{} -> {}'.format(name, value))
```

Comment: print ('{} -> {}'.format(name,i.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.get(name,i.currentframe().f_back.f_globals.get(name))))

Comment: @pn1dude, added an alternative solution. Check it out.

Comment: I tried this and my output was 'DEBUG' -> DEBUG
'BATCH' -> BATCH

Comment: @pn1dude, ALTERNATIVE version receive variables without quote. `ShowVars(DEBUG, BATCH)`, not `ShowVars('DEBUG', 'BATCH')`. See http://asciinema.org/a/5976 .

Answer (score 1):

```
members = dir(module)
for item in members:
   if not eval('hasattr(module.%s, "__call__")' % item):
      print item, eval("module.%s" % item)
```

Should give you a first pass but you might wish to filter out things that start with _ and other items.

Answer (score 1):

Import inside function is not pretty but it works:

-main.py-

```
from mymodule import *
DEBUG = True
BATCH = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ShowVars(['DEBUG','BATCH'])
```

-mymodule.py-

```
def ShowVars(varlist):
  from main import *
  for name in varlist:
    print('{} -> {}').format(name,eval(name))
```